# Eclipse 4 RCP: What is the difference between Handled ToolItem/Direct ToolItem/Toolcontrol?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

When adding a new item to a toolbar, you are given the option to choose Handled ToolItem, Direct ToolItem and Toolcontrol:

[image]

What is the difference between these three choices? I can't find the documentation for these anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Handled' items are used when you have defined a command id and one or more handlers for the command. In the HandledToolItem you specify the id of the command that is to be executed.

'Direct' items are used when you just want to specify a Java class to be executed without using a command id and separate handler.

Toolcontrol is used when you want to write you own code for the control in the tool bar (something like a Combo for example).